# ReactJS this.props not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im setting a simple property on a button, and trying to display it in the DOM... I dont understand what I'm doing wrong. I see `Click Me! Current numer is`, but not `Click Me! Current numer is 1`. I have to be missing something? No errors.

```
class TestElement extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    <button currentNumber={1}>Click Me! Current numer is {this.props.currentNumber}</button>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how React works, please [read the docs!](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React sends props down the chain.  In `TestElement.render()`, `this.props` refers to any properties passed to the `TestElement`, eg:

```
class TestElement extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <span>My Name Is {this.props.name}</span>
        );
    }
}
```

rendered like so:

```
<TestElement name="One" />
```

Hopefully this shows that your line

```
<button currentNumber={1}>Click Me! Current numer is {this.props.currentNumber}</button>
```

is confusing what "this" element is.  If you then rendered your TestElement with a `currentNumber` prop, it would appear on your button, but the `currentNumber={1}` attribute on the button will simply be ignored.

### Edit

You could create a custom button something like this:

```
class MyCustomButton extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click Me!  Current number is {this.props.number} />
        );
    }
}

class TestElement extends Component {
    constructor () {
        this.state = {
            number: 1
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                 <h1>The Buttonater!</h1>
                 <MyCustomButton number={this.state.number} onClick={this.onButtonClick} />
            </div>
        );
    }
    onButtonClick () {
        this.setState({
            number: this.state.number + 1
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would need to break the button down to it's own individual component. Then import it with a prop and value on the element.

Comment: If you want to have a custom button which provides content based on its properties, yeah :)

Comment: No problem.  I added an (untested) example.

Answer (score 2):

`this.props` is set for the instance of component you are *defining*. `this` refers to an instance of the class.

In this case `this.props` refers to the props for some instance of `TestElement`.

If you want to work with the props you pass to the button component, you'll have to define it as a child component.

```
class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button ...this.props>{this.props.currentNumber}</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Then instead use an instance of this component.

```
<Button currentNumber={1} />
```